# Remove <div class="container"> between Navbar and Navbar.Header React Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

When I work with Navbar and Navbar.Header from [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/), on Inspect I see a `<div class="container">` as image bellow, I don't know why, so could you help me remove it
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove `container` you should pas `fluid` prop to `Navbar`.

The `fluid` prop allows the `Navbar` to fluidly adjust to the page or container width, instead of at the predefined screen breakpoints.

Example:

```
<Navbar fluid>
  ...
</Navbar>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try.